# How to text replace dash or hyperlink symbol correctly in REACT

Tags: reactjs

Im currently using this syntax to strip my text

```
export const stripTags = (str = "") => str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
```

but it's returning some of the values such as `&nbsp;` or `&mdash;`
if theres like a "-" or hyperlink on the text..

How can i return them as it is while also removing any  or headings on the text ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
const stripTags = (str = "") => str.replace(/&nbsp;|&mdash;|<([^>]+)>/gi, "");
```

Comment: This works. but how can i exclude links from  being replace? at the moment

hyperlinks will return &nbsp instead..

&nbsp;poll&nbsp;